# Majorupgrade or Upgrade ID which is preferred for Major upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, major-upgrade

We are trying to do Major upgrade. While i was investigating i found 2 approaches.

One is using Upgrade Id and another one approach was Majorupgrade tag.

It seems Majorupgrade is easy to do it seems. But schedule doesn't contain any before installinitialize action.

I am not sure which should be using .

Which one is preferred [and recommended] mostly?

Comment: Schedule has the option "afterInstallValidate" which is before InstallInitialize.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [MajorUpgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_majorupgrade.htm) element was introduced in wix 3.5 to simplify what you would normally do with the [Upgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_upgrade.htm) element. So that instead of something like this:

```
<!– Major upgrade –> 
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)"> 
    <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" /> 
    <UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" /> 
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence> 
    <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallValidate" /> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Condition Message="Can't downgrade"> 
    NOT NEWERVERSIONDETECTED 
</Condition>
```

You can simply do this:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Can’t downgrade." />
```

Not only is the old way more verbose, it also requires that you repeat the upgrade code and product version which are specified in the [Product](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_product.htm) element. So the sample above has to make use of wix variables to keep them in sync. If you get that wrong, the upgrade won't work correctly.

The new `MajorUpgrade` element has none of those complications, so I recommend that you use it. See also this [blog post by Bob Arnson introducing `MajorUpgrade`](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/01/16/major-upgrades-now-easier-than-ever/) and the [topic in the wix documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/major_upgrade.htm) on the subject.

Comment: I needed a feature not available with `MajorUpgrade` (i.e., allow major upgrade from old versions but not from very old versions), so your answer was extremely useful in "converting" `MajorUpgrade` to the equivalent (and more customizable) "old-style" code. Thanks!